# Get list of Virtual directories from IIS using command prompt

Tags: iis, command

Is there a way to get a list of Virtual directories under a specific website in IIS using the command prompt?

I was able to perform the task using C# but I have a specific requirement where-in I need to list all the virtual directories under a website using the command prompt.

Comment: Can you use PowerShell or VbScript? You can easily query the WMI provider with either of those. I'm not sure off the top of my head with the cmd prompt.

Comment: @codemonkeh You could write an answer for one or both anyway. Both kinds of script can be invoked from a command prompt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOS command to list all virtual directories in IIS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218046/dos-command-to-list-all-virtual-directories-in-iis-6)

Comment: Another possible solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938467/list-all-virtual-directories-in-iis-5-6-and-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
appcmd list vdir /app.name:[sitename]/
```

Replace *[sitename]* with the name of your site.

For more info, check out [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771588%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).